# Facebook returning empty array from /me/friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

So I am use the 2.3 API Version trying to access the /me/friends list that returns all of my friends who are also using the app. Except, it always returns the following:

```
{
  "data": [
  ], 
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 889
  }
}
```

I have tried using the Graph Explorer as well as the JS Sdk right within the browser with no luck.

I am requesting the `user_friends` permission and it is actually included by default. And yes, I have many friends who have been using our app. I debugged the token online via Facebook's debugger and concluded the token does indeed have that permission.

NOTE: Our app isn't listed in the Facebook app store. It is however Live and available to the public.

Can someone help?

Comment: Friends need to have granted `user_friends` permission as well.

Answer (score 5):

- A user access token with user_friends permission is required to view the current person's friends.
- This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app + making the request.
- If a friend of the person declines the user_friends permission, that friend will not show up in the friend list for this person.
- If user-a is friends with user-b in the above request, the response will contain the User object for user-b. If they are not friends, it will return an empty dataset.

Did you check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/friends) ?